# buffered reader server while(in.read() != -1)

Tags: java, servidor, socket

Quando me conecto pelo navegador em localhost:80 no servidor cujo código em Java está abaixo, o servidor lê os dados da requisição usando métodos da classe `BufferedReader`.

No entanto, o servidor está exibindo os dados da requisição com uma letra de cada linha faltando. Por exemplo, "GET" está como "ET" e "host" está como "ost". Segue um exemplo do que ele capturou em uma requisição:

```
ET / HTTP/1.1
ost: localhost
onnection: keep-alive
pgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
ser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36
ec-Fetch-Dest: document
ccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
ec-Fetch-Site: none
ec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
ec-Fetch-User: ?1
ccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
ccept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Eis o código correspondente:

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class BufferedReaderServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80);
        System.out.println("Server");



        while (true) {
            try {

            Socket client = server.accept();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 





            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            //print.println(abc);

            while(in.read() != -1) {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
            }



            }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Já sei onde está o problema e como corrigir e só estou esperando reabrir a pergunta para postar uma resposta.

Comment: Ah, e é claro, se você tivesse descrito o problema de forma clara e prezado por uma boa redação, não teriam fechado a pergunta.

Comment: comunidades parecem que não gostam de perguntas abstratas e objetivas com um fim. essa foi a única pergunta que me responderam e isso porque foi só 1 erro rápido; eu tinha feito int input;
         while((input = i.read()) != -1) {
          System.out.print(input + ":");
          w.println(input);
         }

Comment: o que eu queria mesmo saber é porque eu não consigo dar PrintWriter em um readLine do BuffeRed dessa forma:          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 

            String input;
         while((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(input);
          w.println(input);
         }

Comment: Eu tenho 1001 perguntas, mas eles me exluem de todas comunidades, me dão voto negativo, dizem qeu eu sou inciainte quando nem sabe o que isso significa;

Por que o google functions usa nodejs e não java? porque o mysql não permite facilmente bloquear o phpmyadmin sem firewall? porque não existe uma solução tudo em um de um banco de dados java sem servidor com opção de cache cluster e gui para portabilidade multi plataforma para não ter que configurar mil vezes. ou shell multi btach em java para controlar instancias e abrir todas instancias sem ter que decidir entre shell e batch e compilar2x

Comment: Calma rapaz. Ninguém aqui está te atacando. Eu só estava te ajudando. Tanto é que fui eu que consegui fazer a sua pergunta ser reaberta e até dei uma resposta a ela.

Comment: O StackOverflow tem uma forma de funcionamento que é bem diferente de outros sites mesmo, e isso sempre gerou muito atrito. Até se acostumar em como as coisas funcionam é algo um tanto difícil mesmo. O que acontece é que perguntas excessivamente abertas e com poucos detalhes dificilmente têm informações suficientes para que possam ser respondidas com alguma resposta razoável,  por isso elas são fechadas. Mas isso é algo simples de resolver, basta se esforçar um pouquinho na redação da pergunta e tentar colocar nelas todas as informações necessárias, e a pergunta será aceita.

Comment: Ah, e quanto aos votos, está nesse momento +1/-2. O +1 é meu.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que quando você dá o `in.read()`, você consome um caractere da linha a ser lida e não o armazena em lugar nenhum, e portanto ele acaba sendo perdido.

A solução seria fazer o seguinte:

```java
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class BufferedReaderServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80);
        System.out.println("Server");

        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 
                PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                //print.println(abc);

                while (true) {
                    String linha = in.readLine();
                    if (linha == null) break;
                    System.out.println(linha);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isso se aproveita do fato de que o `readLine()` retorna `null` quando a entrada a acaba e retorna alguma string enquanto houver entrada a ser consumida.